# Cat palm is yellow and drooping

Tags: palm

I got this cat palm about 3 weeks ago and it’s been going down hill. I have a soil thermometer and only water when the soil is on the dry side by touch or the thermometer. I water it from the bottom. I have a humidifier on it that keeps the humidity about 65%. I’m in an apartment and have a north eastern facing window (I think). It gets light but maybe not enough?

I’ve read this forum up and down. I think it might have spider mites so I took rubbing alcohol to wipe the leaves down. I cut off some of the yellowing fronds but now new fronds are turning yellow. This is my first cat palm and it’s not easy! Can she be saved??

[image: enter image description enter image description herehere]

Comment: Could it just be stress from moving to a new place? Do you know what the conditions in the previous place were? If she was in a greenhouse, then the 65% humidity will still feel like a shock. What are the daytime and night-time temperatures?